# how can i get checkbox name when checked without submit button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, checkbox

My code is there,

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query2)) 
{
echo "<tr>";
$ids = $row['list_id'];
echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='checkbox[]' value=" . $ids . "></td>";
echo "<td>" . $ids . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['list_name'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['campaign_id'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['list_description'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['list_changedate'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['list_lastcalldate'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['reset_time'] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
```

And

```
<a href="import.php"><input type="button" value="Import Leads to List"></a>
```

I wanna pass the checked checkbox value on the URL when button clicked.
Like this,

```
Http://localhost/test/import.php?id=1234
```

if multiple multiple checkboxes checked, I wanna print error message or alert box like,

```
Please Select any one List ID!
```

Please help me..
thank you

Comment: use radio button instead checkbox so user will able to select only one

Comment: should note that all the rows generated have one checkbox having the same `id='checkbox'`, that's not valid, although your code can run OK in some cases.

Comment: @EhsanSajjad well that's the HTML right there.. he's injecting it using php...

Comment: and btw you are using old outdated  mysql_* function ....and it wont work in new php versions check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php/14110189#14110189

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1) *change `id='checkbox'` to valid `class='checkbox'`* **EDIT**: add `class='checkbox'`;

2) Use jQuery function to check checked checkboxes cound and to get name:

```
$('button').click(function(){
    if ($('.checkbox:checked').length !== 1) {
       alert("Please Select any one List ID!");
    } else {
        *var url = window.location.href + '?id=' + $('.checkbox:checked').eq(0).attr('name');*
         **EDIT**:
         var url = window.location.href + '?id=' + $('.checkbox:checked').eq(0).val();
         $('a').attr('href', url);
    }
});
```

---

**EDIT** "What if i have multiple buttons":

Replace checkbox in loop with `<a href='index.php?id=<?php echo $ids; ?>'><button>Import to List</button></a>`, and there will be no need for js manipulation.

**OR**

Change checkbox: `<td><input type='checkbox' onClick='changeUrl(this)' data-link-id='UniqueIdOfLink'`, and instead of `$('button').click` make function:

```
function changeUrl(e) {
    $('#' + $(e).data('link-id')).attr('href', 'index.php?id=' + $(e).val());
}
```

Comment: You might want to actually assign the new value to the href… i think that's what the OP want..

Comment: If i use multiple buttons on a page?

Answer (score 2):

First of all as others said, use radiobutton instead checkbox so users can select only one. Since you haven't posted your HTML code I can only provide you a sketchy scheme:
(I use native JS, but you can make it in jQuery)

the PHP+HTML:

```
<form action="" name="name_of_form">
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query2)) {
   echo "<tr>";
   $ids = $row['list_id'];
   echo "<td><input type='radio' name='radio[]' onclick='setURL(this.value)' value=".$ids."></td>";
   echo "<td>" . $ids . "</td>";
   echo "<td>" . $row['list_name'] . "</td>";
   echo "<td>" . $row['campaign_id'] . "</td>";
   echo "<td>" . $row['list_description'] . "</td>";
   echo "<td>" . $row['list_changedate'] . "</td>";
   echo "<td>" . $row['list_lastcalldate'] . "</td>";
   echo "<td>" . $row['reset_time'] . "</td>";
   echo "</tr>";
}
?>
<input type="submit" value='Import Leads to List'/>
</form>
```

The javascript:

```
function setURL(id){
     document.name_of_form.action="Http://localhost/test/import.php?id="+id;
}
```

Note that if you use forms you don't have to manually monkey around the url, you can just use $_POST.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready( function () {

$('button').click(function(){

var dea = $("input[type='checkbox']").attr('value');
    window.location.href = 'http://localhost/test/import.php?id='+dea;
});

});
```

if you want to select only one option at a time you will use a radio button.

Comment: You can check if user selected only one option, so it's possible to use checkbox too.

Comment: yes but in checkbox have to set conditions while in radio box just the same name will work. Short and Easy